# Java Character: Is there a value for "Not A Character"?

Tags: java, character

In Java, for `Double`, we have a value for `NaN` (Not A Number).

Now, for `Character`, do we have a similar equivalent for "Not A Character"?

If the answer is no, then I think a safe substitute may be `Character.MIN_VALUE` (which is of type `char` and has value `\u0000`).  Do you think this substitute is safe enough? Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: what about `null`?

Comment: My motivation is like why `NaN` is needed for `Double`, that sometimes a value of type `Double` needs to be passed around, but the value really is not a double floating point value.  Well ... as I was typing this response, I realized that I could use `null`, or, in Java 8 and for the cases where the value is one returned from a function, I can use `Optional<Character>` as Reimeus has suggested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, there is a concept of "not a number" - 5 divided by 0 is not a number. Since this concept exists, there is `NaN` for the `double` type.

Characters are an abstract concept of mapping numbers to characters. The idea of "not a character" doesn't really exist, since the charset in use can vary (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.).

Think of it this way. If I ask you, "what is 5 divided by 0?", you would say it's "not a number". But, we do have a defined way to represent the value, even though it's not a number. If I draw a random squiggle and ask you, "what letter is this?", you would say "it's not a letter". But, we *don't* have a way to actually represent that squiggle outside of what I just drew. There's no real way to communicate the "non-character" I've just drawn, but there is a way to communicate the "non-number" of 5 divided by 0.

`\u0000` is the null character, which is still a character. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Depending on your goal `\u0000` may suffice.

Comment: Yes, I agree that actually `null` would be good enough.  Or, in Java 8 and for the cases where the value is one returned from a function, I can use `Optional<Character>` as Reimeus has suggested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "not-a-number" concept does not really belong to Java; rather, Java defines `double` as being [IEEE 754 double precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which have that concept. (That said, if I recall correctly, Java does specify some details about NaN that IEEE 754 leaves open to implementations.)

The analogous standard for Java `char` is Unicode: Java defines `char` as being [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code units.

Unicode does have various reserved-undefined characters that you could use; for example, [U+FFFF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffff/index.htm) (`'\uFFFF'`) will never be a character. Alternatively, you could use [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) (`'\uFFFD'`), which *is* a character, but is specifically the "replacement character" suitable for replacing garbage or invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you're trying to do. If you're trying to represent the lack of a character you could do

```
Optional<Character> noCharacter = Optional.empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the character's code is greater than or equal to the value of 'a' and less than or equal to the value of 'Z'. That would qualify as not a character if by not a character, you mean an alphabet letter. You could extend it to symbols like question mark, full stop, comma etc, but if you want to go further than ASCII territory, I think it gets out of hand.

One other approach would be to check if something is a number. If it's not, you could check if it's a white character, then if it's not, everything else qualifies as a character, therefore you get your answer. 
It's a long discussion IMO, because answers vary, depending on your view on what's a character.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  But my question is actually about "how to represent such a value", not about "how to determine a value is a character or not".  For the purpose of my question, I accept the other suggestions that may be `null` would be good enough.